# HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Please help me....
I am getting below stacktrace in my console. I tried to replace the hibernate jar also for this but it did not work. Can anybody help me in resolving below mapping exception.

Please find my stacktrace below:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use 
>       org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1606)
>       org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1561)
>       org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1540)
>       org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1514)
>       org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1434)
>       org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1420)
>       org.mm.hibernate.CityDBHelper.getAllCities(CityDBHelper.java:15)
>       com.MM.Services.CityService.getCities(CityService.java:27)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:350)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:319)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>       org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.MM</groupId>
<artifactId>Services</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Services</name>

<build>
    <finalName>Services</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
        <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>




    <!-- MySQL Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL Dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Validation API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cglib/cglib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-collections/commons-collections -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.transaction/jta -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/taglibs/standard -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.6</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

My DBHelper class

```
public class CityDBHelper {
    public List<City> getAllCities() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Query query = session.createQuery("from City");
        List<City> listCity = query.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return listCity;
    }

    public boolean addCityCSV(String cityNames, int stateId) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        String[] cityArr = cityNames.split(",");
        for(String c : cityArr) {
            City city = new City();
            city.setCityName(c.trim());

            city.setStateId(stateId);
            session.save(city);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
<groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.3.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

try this

Comment: did you changed to AnnotationConfiguration instead of Configuration?

Comment: Yes.. I also tried that but it did not solve my problem.